# Merge data from different rows to different columns

Tags: sql

I have a table (T)

```
User | Language | Value
-----------------------
1    |1         | string
1    |2         | otherString
```

and want to merge/join them to get this

```
User | Language_1 | Language_2
--------------------------------
1    |string      | otherString
```

I tried something like this

```
SELECT       USER,
             (CASE WHEN Language = 1 THEN Value END) AS language_1,
             (CASE WHEN Language = 2 THEN Value END) AS language_2
FROM         T
```

But I get something like this as result (I should have expected this)

```
User | Language_1 | Language_2
--------------------------------
1    |string      | NULL
1    |NULL        | otherString
```

Whats the right way to do it?

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: You really should avoid using reserved words as object or column names. USER and Language are both reserved words.

Comment: @SeanLange indeed weren't thinking about it, gonna give it an edit when I am home from work

Answer (score 2):

You just need an aggregation

```
SELECT USER,
         MAX(CASE WHEN Language = 1 THEN Value END) AS language_1,
         MAX(CASE WHEN Language = 2 THEN Value END) AS language_2
FROM  T
GROUP BY USER
```